# Generating nice-looking static websites from LaTeX?

Tags: packages, html, online, css, markup

I notice that a lot of researchers tend to have crappy-looking websites, often because they aren't willing to put in the time it takes to learn HTML, CSS, and design principles--they'd rather do research.  I'm assuming that said researchers know LaTeX, as it's pretty much the standard for academic typesetting.  So why not leverage that knowledge to make a kick-ass homepage?  **Are there any LaTeX packages or tools that are designed with the easy creation of a nice-looking website in mind?**  And, no, I don't mean just haphazardly turning a topology paper into a Web page.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of other tex to html conversion questions apart from the opinion based comments on other techniques, so I voted to close on that basis, sorry,

Comment: I don't think so. TeX (et al), after all, is about putting things (mostly text and maths) nicely on a page of fixed dimensions. Websites are not about fixed dimensions, etc. In fact, if the *primary goal* of some bit of text and so on is for it to end up in HTML/CSS, I doubt many people here will encourage others to write it in *TeX. (Not that it's impossible, just that it's not the right starting point.)

Comment: @jon I would encourage it :) it is good starting point, but you needs to know some limitations from the beginning

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289562/2891 and https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ht-enhanced-web and directly related to static sites is this project: https://github.com/michal-h21/jekyll4ht

Comment: @michal.h21 -- Well, naturally, you'd be one of the exceptions! I hope to find time to try your `jekyll4ht` some time (though I do find `tex4ht` to be a finicky thing to use).